# What can I do with Prism Event Aggregator that cannot be done using bubbling/tunneling?

Tags: wpf

Imagine a Visual Studio type user interface in which there is a left pane and a right pane. I need to send a message/event that originates in the left pane to an element in the right pane. As a WPF newbie, I have the following linked questions:

1. Can this be done using bubbling and tunneling events?
2. If the answer is 'yes', which is better: bubbling/tunneling, or Prism's event aggregator?

Comment: What kind of event do you want to send? Is this a view related event (e.g. mouse or visibility change)?

Comment: In the left pane I have a dialog through which I would like the user to control the appearance of a shape in the right pane. So for example the user enters the desired width and height in the left pane, hits the 'apply' button, and sees the rectangle in the right pane honor the dimensions immediately

Comment: Well, in this case I would suggest the MVVM design pattern, whereby your shape would be the model and both panes would have dedicated view models that have references to the same model (or a collection of models). So hitting the **Apply** button will cause the first view model to update the shape object, and the second view model could do its specific work, as your model would implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I use Event Aggregation to notify my 'panes' of events that happen and both need to respond.

So, for one example, I would subscribe both 'panes' to an event. Now, say I kick of a request to the database or webservice, and upon return of results I want to notify both 'panes' simultaneously that data has arrived. I can easily do this by publishing to my event, then both 'panes' will kick off whatever they need to.

I like this way, because then if I had another module dropped in the left 'pane', all I would need to do is subscribe to that event to respond to any data coming in.